# How can i read a .txt file from a website with WP7?

Tags: file, windows-phone-7, text

I'm working on my thesis project and I need to open and read a file from a website. I couldn't find anything. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi Kansu, Could you focus the question for us? I'm hoping you have something specific in mind that you need help with. You've mentioned a thesis project with a need to read a file from a url and rewrite the file and modify some values. This is all fairly broad. You've been given some info so far on pulling the data down from a website which seems to go a fair way in answering your initial question. Does this help? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). If you just want the contents as a string, it could be something like:

```
WebClient cli = new WebClient();
cli.DownloadStringCompleted += // your completed handler
cli.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

Because all network IO on WP7 is asynchronous, you have to attach an event handler and wait for the event to be raised before you get the data.

Comment: Can I download the textfile on the website to Isolated Storage and work on it like that?

Comment: Sure, `WebClient` has the OpenRead method that gives you a Stream. You can save that yo Isolated Storage.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the HttpWebRequest Class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) [This video should help you also.](http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/mtaulty/silverlight-using-httpwebrequest)

Answer (score 0):

well,HttpRequest can reads the file,but i need to download the file before reading it,i need to change some variables inside the txt file

and this is the file that i download

http://dhmi.gov.tr/UcusBilgileri/1/domarr.txt

Comment: It would be preferable to not create answers with supplementary information about your question. You are able to respond in comments to the answers given you so far if you need clarification on the answers given, or edit your original question if you would like to provide supplementary information.

Answer (score 0):

You can only IsolatedStorage for file IO in Windows Phone 7

For downloading the text file, the easiest way would probably to use the WebClient's DownloadString() method. Then write the contents of this file to the IsolatedStorage.

This might also interest you:
http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/05/06/windows-phone-7-development-using-isolated-storage.aspx